# RabbitMQ cluster (classic config) split

Tags: configuration, rabbitmq

I try to configure RabbitMQ cluster in a cloud using config file.

My procedure is this:

1. Get list of instances I want to cluster with (via cloud API, before cluster startup).
2. Modify config file like that:

   ```
   cluster_formation.peer_discovery_backend = rabbit_peer_discovery_classic_config
   cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.1 = rabbit@host1.my.long.domain.name
   cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.2 = rabbit@host2.my.long.domain.name
   ...
   ```
3. Run `rabbitmq-server`

I expect all nodes to cluster but instead there might be 2+ independent clusters. How do I solve this issue?

UPDATE:

I found out that when I run `rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@host.in.existing.cluster` on node that is in some cluster already, this node leaves his previous cluster (I expected this clusters to merge). That might be root of the problem.

UPDATE 2:

I have 4 instances. 3 run bare `rabbitmq-servers`, 1 is configured to join other 3. When started, it joins with the last instance in its config, 2 others show no activity in threir logs. Happens on classic config and erlang config both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initially start up your cluster, there is no means to resolve race condition. Using peer discovery backends will not help with this issue (tested on `etcd`).

What actually resolved this issue is **not deploying instances simultaneously**. When started one by one everything is fine and you get one stable cluster which can handle scaling without failure.